# How can one use regex to capture the text occurring between lines beginning with a single semicolon?

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture the text between lines which begin with single semicolons:

sample input:

```
s = '''
;

the color blue

;

the color green

;

the color red

;
'''
```

this is the desired output:

```
['the color blue', 'the color green', 'the color red']
```

this attempted solution doesn't work:

```
import re
pat = r'^;(.*)^;'
r = re.findall(pat, s, re.S|re.M)
print(r)
```

this is the wrong output:

```
['\n\nthe color blue\n\n;\n\nthe color green\n\n;\n\nthe color red\n\n']
```

Comment: put `\n\n` after the semi-colon and after the capture group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it like delimiters.

`(?sm)^;\s*\r?\n(.*?)\s*(?=^;\s*\r?\n)`

https://regex101.com/r/4tKX0F/1

Explained

```
 (?sm)                         # Modifiers: dot-all, multi-line
 ^ ; \s* \r? \n                # Begining delimiter
 ( .*? )                       # (1), Text 
 \s*                           # Wsp trim
 (?= ^ ; \s* \r? \n )          # End delimiter
```

Comment: Thanks! -- this regex handles all the possible variations I had in mind -- zero or more blank lines following delimiter lines, multiple lines in the text and any characters in the text.

Answer (score 1):

Non-regex solution,I split on `;` and remove null strings

```
s = '''
    ;

    the color blue


;

the color green

;

the color red

;
'''

f = s.split(';')


x = [a.strip('\n') for a in f]

print(x) #prints ['', 'the color blue', 'the color green', 'the color red', '']

a = [elem for elem in x if len(elem)]

print(a) #prints ['the color blue', 'the color green', 'the color red']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this as the pattern:

```
pat = r';\n\n([\w* *]*)'

r = re.findall(pat, s)
```

That should capture what you need.

Comment: I see multiple problems with this regex. 1) It relies on the presence of two empty lines right after each semicolon. 2) It only captures a single line of text, i.e. it won't grab the `b` from `;\n\na\nb` - in fact, any non-space, non-word, non-asterisk character between `a` and `b` will break it. 3) `[\w* *]` doesn't do what you think it does, it's equivalent to `[\w \*]`.

Comment: It captures everything on his test. What would you recommend instead of `[\w* *]`?

Comment: Take note of @Rawing 's scripture - I sense wisdom in his teachings ^^

Comment: What if one wanted the regex to be able to capture any text (including multiple lines with any characters) between lines beginning with a single semicolon and with no empty lines -- for example:

    
`s = '''
;
item 1, item 2; [item 3]: item 4!
item 5? (item 6); item 7: item 8.
;
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
;
'''`

Comment: Ok -- I still don't see a regex that will capture text between lines beginning with single semicolons that may include one or more lines and any characters, and with zero or more blank lines following the lines beginning with semicolons.

Sorry -- I've adjusted my original question a bit to handle a wider range of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `;\s*(.*?)\s*(?=;)`. Usage:

```
print( re.findall(r'(?s);\s*(.*?)\s*(?=;)', s) )
# output: ['the color blue', 'the color green', 'the color red']
```

---

Explanation:

```
(?s)   # dot-all modifier (. matches newlines)
;      # consume a semicolon
\s*    # skip whitespace
(.*?)  # capture the following text, as little as possible, such that...
\s*    # ... it is followed only by (optional) whitespace, and...
(?=;)  # ... a semicolon
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask for this, I know. But it's worth considering **pyparsing** as an alternative to **re**. Indeed, pyparsing properly contains regex. Notice how this simple parser copes with various numbers of empty lines.

```
>>> parsifal = open('temp.txt').read()
>>> print (parsifal)


;

the colour blue
;
the colour green
;
the colour red
;
the colour purple




;

the colour magenta

;


>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> p = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Suppress(';\n')+pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Suppress('\n'))+pp.CharsNotIn(';\n')+pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Suppress('\n')))
>>> p.parseString(parsifal)
(['the colour blue', 'the colour green', 'the colour red', 'the colour purple', 'the colour magenta'], {})
```

As a whole, the parser matches `OneOrMore` sequences of semicolons or new-lines, followed by anything other than these characters followed by new-lines.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to pyparsing -- I am going to explore it.